# How do I correctly use Control.Exception.catch in Haskell?

Tags: exception, haskell

Can someone please explain the difference between the behavior in ghci of the following to lines:

```
catch (return $ head []) $ \(e :: SomeException) -> return "good message"
```

returns

```
"*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

but

```
catch (print $ head []) $ \(e :: SomeException) -> print "good message"
```

returns

```
"good message"
```

Why isn't the first case catching the exception? Why are they different? And why does the first case put a double quote before the exception message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's examine what happens in the first case:

```
catch (return $ head []) $ \(e :: SomeException) -> return "good message"
```

You create thunk `head []` which is `return`ed as an `IO` action. This thunk doesn't throw any exception, because it isn't evaluated, so the whole call `catch (return $ head []) $ ...` (which is of type `IO String`) produces the `String` thunk without an exception. The exception occurs only when ghci tries to print the result afterwards. If you tried

```
catch (return $ head []) $ \(e :: SomeException) -> return "good message"
    >> return ()
```

instead, no exception would have been printed.

This is also the reason why you get _"*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list_. GHCi starts to print the string, which starts with `"`. Then it tries to evaluate the string, which results in an exception, and this is printed out.

Try replacing `return` with `evaluate` (which forces its argument to WHNF) as

```
catch (evaluate $ head []) $ \(e :: SomeException) -> return "good message"
```

then you'll force the thunk to evaluate inside `catch` which will throw the exception and let the handler intercept it.

In the other case

```
catch (print $ head []) $ \(e :: SomeException) -> print "good message"
```

the exception occurs inside the `catch` part when `print` tries to examine `head []` and so it is caught by the handler.

---

**Update:** As you suggest, a good thing is to force the value, preferably to its full normal form. This way, you ensure that there are no "surprises" waiting for you in lazy thunks. This is a good thing anyway, for example you can get hard-to-find problems if your thread returns an unevaluated thunk and it is actually evaluated in another, unsuspecting thread.

Module `Control.Exception` already has `evaluate`, which forces a thunk into its WHNF. We can easily augment it to force it to its full NF:

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Seq
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad

toNF :: (NFData a) => a -> IO a
toNF = evaluate . withStrategy rdeepseq
```

Using this, we can create a strict variant of `catch` that forces a given action to its NF:

```
strictCatch :: (NFData a, Exception e) => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a
strictCatch = catch . (toNF =<<)
```

This way, we are sure that the returned value is fully evaluated, so we won't get any exceptions when examining it. You can verify that if you use `strictCatch` instead of `catch` in your first example, it works as expected.

Comment: To me this begs the question: is there a catch-like tool that ensures that the handler is run in such a situation? If not, would it be at all desirable? After all, given just the signature `(IO a) -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a` I would expect the final `IO a` to be 'guarded' no matter what. Incidentally the documentation for `catch` is clear enough to explain the particular semantics (paraphrasing: 'run the computation, and possibly catch now and only now'), but what to call them?

Comment: Hazarding a guess, I would suspect that it has to do with strictness and the fact that we're not only catching exceptions for a 'lazy I/O' value, but we're doing it in that selfsame 'lazy I/O' world with its associated pitfalls. I imagine that imprecise use of resources is exactly what you *don't* want to do on the exceptional path. I would be really glad if someone knowledgeable would chime in now, and I'm still interested to know if a hypothetical `length (return (head []) \`lazyCatch\` (\(e :: SomeException) -> return "") == 0` makes sense.

Comment: @LucDanton I haven't seen such a catch-like tool, but it's not difficult to build one. I added such a variant of `strictCatch` to the answer. It fully evaluates the result of an action so that we can be sure there are no hidden exceptions in its returned value.

Comment: @PetrPudlák is this a consequence of using ghci or really the behavior  of the catch function? It would seem that catch should always be strict, or is there a valid use-case for lazy catch?

Comment: @HaskellElephant It's the same when you use the value of `catch` in further processing, like in `catch ... >>= print`, it's not specific to ghci. Perhaps lazy catch could be used in lazy IO, but lazy IO should be always avoided anyway. But values can also be functions like `IO (a -> b)` for which there is no meaningful way how to force their evaluation. So we can't just automatically force evaluation of everything.

Answer (score 10):

```
return $ head []
```

wraps `head []` in an IO action (because `catch` has an `IO` type, otherwise it would be any monad) and returns it. There is nothing caught because there is no error. `head []` itself is not evaluated at that point, thanks to lazyness, but only returned.
So, `return` only adds a layer of wrapping, and the result of your whole catch expression is `head []`, quite valid, unevaluated. Only when GHCi or your program actually try to use that value at some later point, it will be evaluated and the empty list error is thrown - at a different point, however.

```
print $ head []
```

on the other hand immediately evaluates `head []`, yielding an error which is subsequently caught.

You can also see the difference in GHCi:

```
Prelude> :t head []
head [] :: a

Prelude> :t return $ head []
return $ head [] :: Monad m => m a

Prelude> :t print $ head []
print $ head [] :: IO ()

Prelude> return $ head [] -- no error here!

Prelude> print $ head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

To avoid that, you can perhaps just force the value:

```
Prelude> let x = head [] in x `seq` return x
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Answer (score 6):

[GHCi works in the `IO` monad](http://www.haskell.org/ghc//docs/7.2-latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) and `return` for `IO` doesn't force its argument. So `return $ head []` doesn't throw any exception, and an exception that isn't thrown can't be caught. *Printing* the result afterwards throws an exception, but this exception isn't in the scope of `catch` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The type `IO a` has two parts:

- The *structure*, the part that goes out and performs side-effects. This is represented by `IO`.
- The *result*, the pure value held inside. This is represented by `a`.

The `catch` function only catches exceptions when they break through the `IO` structure.

In the first example, you call `print` on the value. Since printing a value requires performing I/O with it, any exceptions raised within the value end up in the structure itself. So `catch` intercepts the exception and all is well.

On the other hand, `return` does not inspect its argument. In fact, you are guaranteed by the monad laws that calling `return` does not affect the structure at all. So your value simply passes right through.

So if your code isn't affected by the exception, then where is the error message coming from? The answer is, surprisingly, outside your code. GHCi implicitly tries to `print` every expression that is passed to it. But by then, we are already outside the scope of the `catch`,  hence the error message you see.