# Why catch is not working?

Tags: haskell, input

I am trying to read an Int from the input and managing a bad input from the user.

This a piece of code that does the job but it seems it is not working...

```
asknumplayers = do {
putStr "Please the number of other players:\n";
numstr <- getLine;
maybenum <- catch  (return (Just (read numstr::Int))) (\(e::SomeException) -> return Nothing);
case maybenum of
    Nothing -> asknumplayers;
    Just num -> return num; 
}
```

And this is the main:

```
main = do {
num <- asknumplayers;
putStr $ "Thank you, ready to play against "++ (show num) ++" players?!\n";
}
```

The problem is that the I still get "*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse" when the string is printed in the main.
Is it a problem of lazy evaluation? How should I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I correctly use Control.Exception.catch in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18052619/1333025).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is caused by lazy evaluation. The code `return (Just (read numstring))` will not cause the read to happen, that will only happen in `main` when `putStr` evaluates (*forces*) the string.

Do not use exceptions for that, but rather a more suitable function like [`readMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) from `Text.Read`, or one of the functions from the [`Safe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safe/latest/doc/html/Safe.html) module in the `safe` package.